# How to find all occurrence of a key in nested dict, but also keep track of the outer dict key value?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I've searched over stackoverflow and found the following code that allow me to search for a key values in nested dict recursively. However, I also want to keep track of the outer dict's key value. How should I do that?

from Alfe's answer in the below link, I can use the code below get all the values of the key in nested dict.
[Find all occurrences of a key in nested python dictionaries and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists)

```
data = {'item1': {
  'name': 'dummy',
  'type': 'dummy1'},

'item2': {
  'name': 'dummy',
  'type': 'dummy1',
  'label':'label2'
},

'item3': {
  'name': 'dummy',
  'type': 'dummy1',
  'label':'label3'},

'item4': {
  'name': 'dummy',
  'type': 'dummy1'}
}

 def find(key, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k == key:
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find(key, v):
                yield result
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                for result in find(key, d):
                    yield result


In[1]:list(find('label', data))
Out[1]: 
['label2', 'label3']
```

However, I also need to keep record of the outer dict key as below. How should I do this? Also my data can potentially have more than one layer.

```
{'item2':'label2',
'item3':'label3'
}
```

I also find the recursive_lookup in this link very neatly written. However, it's returning `None` when I tried to run it.

[Find keys in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314755/find-keys-in-nested-dictionary)

```
def recursive_lookup(k, d):
    if k in d:
        return d[k]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return recursive_lookup(k, v)
    return None
```

It's returning `None` when I call `recursive_lookup('label', data)`.

If anyone can point out for me why the above code is not working that would be great too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work regardless of how deep your nesting is (up to the stack limit, at any rate). The request for keeping track of the dict's key is a little awkward--I used a tuple to return the pair. Note that if the found value is in the outermost dictionary, it won't be in the tuple format.

```
def recursive_lookup(key, d):
    if key in d:
        return d[key]

    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result = recursive_lookup(key, v)

            if result:
                return k, result


print(recursive_lookup('label', data))
```

Output:

```
('item2', 'label2')
```

Here's a version that's a little messier (I'm not crazy about an inner function, but at least the accumulator list isn't a parameter and isn't global) but will return a list of all found items nested up to the stack limit, excepting the outermost keys:

```
def recursive_lookup(key, d):
    def _lookup(key, d):
        if key in d:
            return d[key]

        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                result = _lookup(key, v)

                if result:
                    accumulator.append((k, result))

    accumulator = []
    _lookup(key, d)
    return accumulator
```

Output:

```
[('item3', 'label3'), ('item2', 'label2')]
```

This can be easily modified if you want to output a dict--replace `accumulator = []` with `accumulator = {}` and `accumulator.append((k, result))` with `accumulator[k] = result`, but this might be awkward to work with, and you can't store duplicate key entries.

As for your final question, the reason you're getting `None` is because the inner loop `returns` after checking the first item whether it found something or not. Since `label` is in the second location of the `items()` array, it never gets looked at.

Comment: thanks @ggorlen. Looks like it's only returning the first instance of the key, but not the full list. Just wondering how do I make it find all the occurrences of the key?

Comment: I added that--wasn't sure which one you wanted based on your question.

Answer (score 2):

functions returns the path as well as value as a list of tuple.

```
def dict_key_lookup(_dict, key, path=[]):
    results = []
    if isinstance(_dict, dict):
        if key in _dict:
            results.append((path+[key], _dict[key]))
        else:
            for k, v in _dict.items():
                results.extend(dict_key_lookup(v, key, path= path+[k]))
    elif isinstance(_dict, list):
        for index, item in enumerate(_dict):
            results.extend(dict_key_lookup(item, key, path= path+[index]))
    return results
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First create a list like

```
outerKeyList = []
```

Then whenever you want to store a key such as before you return the item you were searching for simply run

```
outerKeyList.append(key).
```

This will give you a convenient list of all the keys outside the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single nested `dict` within your `dict` then you can use a `dict` comprehension:

```
In [9]: def find(label, data):
   ...:     return {outer_key: inner_val for outer_key, outer_val in data.items() for inner_key, inner_val in outer_val.items() if inner_key == label}
   ...:

In [10]: find('label', data)
Out[10]: {'item2': 'label2', 'item3': 'label3'}
```

Comment: thanks @aydow. I do have a dict that can potentially have more than one layer. But this is nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NestedDict`

```
from ndicts import NestedDict

data = {'item1': {'name': 'dummy', 'type': 'dummy1'},
        'item2': {'label': 'label2', 'name': 'dummy', 'type': 'dummy1'},
        'item3': {'label': 'label3', 'name': 'dummy', 'type': 'dummy1'},
        'item4': {'name': 'dummy', 'type': 'dummy1'}}
nd = NestedDict(data)

nd_filtered= NestedDict()
for key, value in nd.items():
    if "label" in key:
        new_key = tuple(level for level in key if level != "label")
        nd_filtered[new_key] = value
```

```
>>> nd_filtered
NestedDict({'item2': 'label2', 'item3': 'label3'})
>>> nd_filtered.to_dict()
{'item2': 'label2', 'item3': 'label3'}
```

You could also consider `.extract`, even though it will not give you exactly the output that you were asking for

```
>>> nd.extract["", "label"]
NestedDict({'item2': {'label': 'label2'}, 'item3': {'label': 'label3'}})
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) `pip install ndicts`