# Python get key of a value inside a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Let's say I have a dictionary called my_dic:

```
my_dict = {'a': {'spam': {'foo': None, 'bar': None, 'baz': None},'eggs': None}, 'b': {'ham': None}}
```

Then if I input `spam`, it should return `a`, and if I input `bar` it should return `spam`. If I input `b`, it should return `None`. Basically getting the parent of the dictionary.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? You’ll need a *recursive* function for starters…

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314755/find-keys-in-nested-dictionary).

Comment: [Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273691/pythonic-way-to-reverse-nested-dictionaries) this for flipping key-values in a dictionary. Maybe you can just keep track of the relationships as you add them into a separated dictionary. Maybe you would benefit more by creating an [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict). What you want to achieve? What is your goal/tasks from hindsight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple recursive function, which returns the current key if `needle in v` is true; `needle in v` simply testing if the key exists in the associated value:

```
my_dict = {'a': {'spam': {'foo': None, 'bar': None, 'baz': None},'eggs': None}, 'b': {'ham': None}}

def get_parent_key(d: dict, needle: str):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if needle in v:
                return k
            
            if found := get_parent_key(v, needle):
                return found
                
print(get_parent_key(my_dict, 'bar'))
```