# How to search inside a Python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a Python dictionary containing recipes. I have to find key values inside it and then return results depending on where those keys where found.

```
recipes = {
    'recipe1':{
        'name': 'NAME',
        'components': {
            '1':{
                'name1':'NAME',
                'percent':'4 %'
            },
            '2':{
                'name2':'NAME',
                'percent':'3 %'
            },
            '3':{
                'name3':'NAME',
                'percent':'1 %'
            },
        },
        'time':'3-5 days',
        'keywords':['recipe1', '1','etc']
    }
}
```

Each recipe has a list of `keywords`. How can I lookup a recipe based on its `keywords` and some search input? Upon finding a recipe, I would need to return the name components and time that are specific for that recipe.

Comment: Why is `keywords` nested inside of `recipe1`? Shouldn't it be up a level? Or possibly even outside of the dictionary? And are the `keywords` supposed to be like the keys of the `dict`?

Comment: @pushkin No, every recipe would have its own set of keywords associated with it, just like every recipe has its own name.

Comment: @chepner oh, duh. I forgot what the word keywords meant outside of a programming context. Thanks

Comment: I believe your question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162321/search-for-a-value-in-a-nested-dictionary-python

Answer (score 2):

Given some input in a variable called `search`, you can do the following:

```
for v in recipes.values():
    if search in v['keywords']:
        # Found the recipe of interest.
        return v['components'], v['time']
```

Unfortunately, the way you are currently storing data prevents you from taking advantage of the `O(1)` lookup time in your dictionary. (This could affect performance if you have several recipes in the `recipes` dictionary.) So you'll have to iterate over the key-value pairs in `recipes` to find a recipe, unless you refactor your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Do like below

```
list = ['etc', 'cc', 'ddd']
for x, y in recipes.items():
    for m in y['keywords']:
        if m in list:
            print('Name : ' + y['name'])
            print('Components : ')
            for i in y['components'].keys():
                print(str(i), end=' ')
                for j in y['components'][i]:
                    print(j + " " + y['components'][i][j], end=' ')
                print('')
            print('\nTime: ' + str(y['time']))
```

**Output:**

```
Name : NAME
Components : 
1 name1 NAME percent 4 % 
2 name2 NAME percent 3 % 
3 name3 NAME percent 1 % 

Time: 3-5 days
```