# Is there a quick way to check if a nested object property equals a value?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to quickly check if one of the attributes (or nested attributes) in a dictionary is equal to "cat".

The dictionary could look like this:

```
my_dict = {
  'dog': 'woof',
  'child':{
      'duck': 'quack'.
      'grandchild': {
         'best': 'cat'
      }
    }
}
```

Is there a quick way to check if 'cat" is on of the attribute values. I could do something like:

```
if 'cat' in json.dumps(my_dict):
```

But that doesn't solve this edge case:

```
{
  'dog': 'woof',
  'child':{
      'duck': 'quack'.
      'grandchild': {
         'best', 'This is a cat in a sentence, should be found!'
      }
    }
}
```

Any good way to handle this? For this, the dictionaries could be quite large, so looping into each and checking is very computationally expensive.

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162321/search-for-a-value-in-a-nested-dictionary-python

Answer (score 0):

You probably found an answer to this from the comment *Devesh Kumar Singh* made with the link but in case you had trouble with those answers or if someone else comes to look at your question here is an answer:

```
# This will be our test nested dictionary.
d = {
  'dog': 'woof',
  'child':{
      'duck': 'quack',
      'grandchild': {
         'best': 'This is a cat in a sentence, should be found!'
      }
    }
}

def recursive_search(dic, search_key):
    """
    Takes a dictionary and looks for the desired key
    at both the top level and for all nested dicts.
    """
    # If the key is in the current dict
    # at top level then return true
    if search_key in dic:
        return True
    # Else we need to make sure it isn't in a nested dict
    # For each key value pair in our current dict
    for cur_key, val in dic.items():
        # If the value for this cur_key is a dict
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            # Check if the nested dic contains our key
            if recursive_search(val, search_key):
                # If it does return true
                return True
            # If it doesn't continue on to the next item in our dict
    # search_key not found.
    return False

print(recursive_search(d, 'best'))
```