# Dictionary: How to list every key path that contains a certain value?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I've got a nested dictionary of the form:

```
{'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white','lakecolor': 'white','caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white',}},
 'title': {'x': 0.05},
 'yaxis': {'automargin': True,'linecolor': 'white','zerolinecolor': 'white','zerolinewidth': 2}
 }
```

How can you work your way through that dict and make a list of each complete key path that contains the value `'white'`?
Using a function defined by user jfs in the post [Search for a value in a nested dictionary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162321/search-for-a-value-in-a-nested-dictionary-python) lets you check whether or not `'white'` occurs at least one time and also returns the path:

```
# dictionary
    d={'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white','lakecolor': 'white','caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white',}},
    'title': {'x': 0.05},
    'yaxis': {'automargin': True,'linecolor': 'white','ticks': '','zerolinecolor': 'white','zerolinewidth': 2}
  }

# function:
def getpath(nested_dict, value, prepath=()):
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        path = prepath + (k,)
        if v == value: # found value
            return path
        elif hasattr(v, 'items'): # v is a dict
            p = getpath(v, value, path) # recursive call
            if p is not None:
                return p
getpath(d,'white')

# out:
('geo', 'bgcolor')
```

But 'white' occurs other places too, like in :

**1.** `d['geo']['lakecolor']`

**2:** `d['geo']['caxis']['gridcolor']`

**3:** `d['yaxis']['linecolor']`

***How can I make sure that the function finds all paths?***

I've tried applying the function above until it returns `none` while eliminating found paths one by one, but that quickly turned into an ugly mess.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect use case to write a generator:

```
def find_paths(haystack, needle):
    if haystack == needle:
        yield ()
    if not isinstance(haystack, dict):
        return
    for key, val in haystack.items():
        for subpath in find_paths(val, needle):
            yield (key, *subpath)
```

You can use it as follows:

```
d = {
    'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white','lakecolor': 'white','caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white',}},
    'title': {'x': 0.05},
    'yaxis': {'automargin': True,'linecolor': 'white','ticks': '','zerolinecolor': 'white','zerolinewidth': 2}
}

# you can iterate over the paths directly...
for path in find_paths(d, 'white'):
    print('found at path: ', path)

# ...or you can collect them into a list:
paths = list(find_paths(d, 'white'))
print('found at paths: ' + repr(paths))
```

The generator approach has the advantage that it doesn't need to create an object to keep all paths in memory at once; they can be processed one by one and immediately discarded. In this case, the memory savings would be rather modest, but in others they may be significant. Also, if a loop iterating over a generator is terminated early, the generator is not going to keep searching for more paths that would be later discarded anyway.

Answer (score 3):

just transform your function so it returns a `list` and don't `return` when something is found. Just add to/extend the list

```
def getpath(nested_dict, value, prepath=()):
    p = []
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        path = prepath + (k,)
        if v == value: # found value
            p.append(path)
        elif hasattr(v, 'items'): # v is a dict
            p += getpath(v, value, path) # recursive call
    return p
```

with your input data, this produces (order may vary depending on python versions where dictionaries are unordered):

```
[('yaxis', 'linecolor'), ('yaxis', 'zerolinecolor'), ('geo', 'lakecolor'), 
('geo', 'caxis', 'linecolor'), ('geo', 'caxis', 'gridcolor'), ('geo', 'bgcolor')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning is what makes the result incomplete. Instead of returning, use a separate list to track your paths. I'm using list `cur_list` here, and returning it at the very end of the loop:

```
d = {
  'geo': {'bgcolor': 'white',
         'caxis': {'gridcolor': 'white', 'linecolor': 'white'},
         'lakecolor': 'white'},
  'title': {'x': 0.05},
  'yaxis': {'automargin': True,
           'linecolor': 'white',
           'ticks': '',
           'zerolinecolor': 'white',
           'zerolinewidth': 2}
}

cur_list = []

def getpath(nested_dict, value, prepath=()):
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        path = prepath + (k,)
        if v == value: # found value
            cur_list.append(path)
        elif isinstance(v, dict): # v is a dict
            p = getpath(v, value, path, cur_list) # recursive call
            if p is not None:
                cur_list.append(p)

getpath(d,'white')
print(cur_list)


# RESULT:
# [('geo', 'bgcolor'), ('geo', 'caxis', 'gridcolor'), ('geo', 'caxis', 'linecolor'), ('geo', 'lakecolor'), ('yaxis', 'linecolor'), ('yaxis', 'zerolinecolor')]
```

Comment: well, it doesn't work for me. I get self referenced lists because you're using a mutable argument that accumulates, also you're appending lists not elements: `[('yaxis', 'linecolor'), ('yaxis', 'zerolinecolor'), [...], [...], ('geo', 'caxis', 'linecolor'), ('geo', 'caxis', 'gridcolor'), [...], ('geo', 'lakecolor'), ('geo', 'bgcolor'), [...]]`

Comment: I took cur_list out of the definition and made it external again.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this functionality for traversing HDF files with `h5py`. This code is a slight alteration of the answer by user114332 which looks for keys instead of values, and additionally yields the needle in the result, in case it is useful to someone else.

```py
import h5py
def find_paths(haystack, needle):
    if not isinstance(haystack, h5py.Group) and not isinstance(haystack, dict):
        return
    
    if needle in haystack:
        yield (needle,)
    
    for key, val in haystack.items():
        for subpath in find_paths(val, needle):
            yield (key, *subpath)
```

Execution:

```py
sf = h5py.File("file.h5py", mode = "w")
g = sf.create_group("my group")
h = g.create_group("my2")
k = sf.create_group("two group")
l = k.create_group("my2")
a = l.create_group("my2")

for path in find_paths(sf, "my2"):
    print('found at path: ', path)
```

which prints the following

```
found at path:  ('my group', 'my2')
found at path:  ('two group', 'my2')
found at path:  ('two group', 'my2', 'my2')
```