# How use wikidata api to access to the statements

Tags: json, api, parsing, wikidata, wikidata-api

I'm trying to get information from Wikidata. For example, to access to "cobalt-70" I use the API.

```
API_ENDPOINT = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php"

query = "cobalt-70"

params = {
    'action': 'wbsearchentities',
    'format': 'json',
    'language': 'en',
    'search': query
}
r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params = params)
print(r.json())
```

So there is a "claims" which gives access to the statements. Is there a best way to check if a value exists in the statement? For example, "cobalt-70" have the value 0.5 inside the property P2114. So how can I check if a value exists in the statement of the entity? As this example.

[image]

Is there an approach to access it. Thank you!

Comment: `r.json()` doesn't have the information you mention in the question or in the image. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @JackFleeting Sorry I forgot the link of the api : https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q18844865

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but if it's close enough, you can probably modify it as necessary:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q18844865.json'
req = requests.get(url)
targets = j_dat['entities']['Q18844865']['claims']['P2114']
for target in targets:    
    values = target['mainsnak']['datavalue']['value'].items()
    for value in values:
        print(value[0],value[1])
```

Output:

```
amount +0.5
unit http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11574
upperBound +0.6799999999999999
lowerBound +0.32
amount +108.0
unit http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q723733
upperBound +115.0
lowerBound +101.0
```

EDIT:
To find property id by value, try:

```
targets = j_dat['entities']['Q18844865']['claims'].items()
for target in targets:   
    line = target[1][0]['mainsnak']['datavalue']['value']
    if isinstance(line,dict):
        for v in line.values():
            if v == "+0.5":
                print('property: ',target[0])
```

Output:

```
property:  P2114
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's not  exactly what i'm looking for. Imagine you have juste the value 0.5 and I want to find out if it exists in statements of "cobalt-70" and returned the property id of 0.5 ("property": "P2114").

Comment: @elitebook190 - I think I understand what you are looking for (hopefully). See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I try a solution which consists to search inside the json object as the solution proposed here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55549654/8374738. I hope it can help. Let's give you the idea.

```
import pprint

def search(d, search_pattern, prev_datapoint_path=''):
    output = []
    current_datapoint = d
    current_datapoint_path = prev_datapoint_path
    if type(current_datapoint) is dict:
        for dkey in current_datapoint:
            if search_pattern in str(dkey):
                c = current_datapoint_path
                c+="['"+dkey+"']"
                output.append(c)
            c = current_datapoint_path
            c+="['"+dkey+"']"
            for i in search(current_datapoint[dkey], search_pattern, c):
                output.append(i)
    elif type(current_datapoint) is list:
        for i in range(0, len(current_datapoint)):
            if search_pattern in str(i):
                c = current_datapoint_path
                c += "[" + str(i) + "]"
                output.append(i)
            c = current_datapoint_path
            c+="["+ str(i) +"]"
            for i in search(current_datapoint[i], search_pattern, c):
                output.append(i)
    elif search_pattern in str(current_datapoint):
        c = current_datapoint_path
        output.append(c)
    output = filter(None, output)
    return list(output)
```

And you just need to use:

```
pprint.pprint(search(res.json(),'0.5','res.json()'))

Output:

["res.json()['claims']['P2114'][0]['mainsnak']['datavalue']['value']['amount']"]
```